# Searching in several tables with django-haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack

I've got the Restaurant and Comment models shown below. The Comment model has a ForeignKey to Restaurant. How can I perform a search in some of the Restaurant fields and in the comment field of the Comment model which returns a list of Restaurant instances?

Thanks

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country=models.ForeignKey(Country)
    city=models.ForeignKey(City)
    street=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street_number=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    postal_code=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class Comment(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = False)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should read the manual: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

look for multivalue:

```
class RestaurantIndex(indexes.SearchIndex): 
     comments = indexes.MultiValueField() 
     def prepare_comments(self, obj): 
         return [a for a in obj.comment_set.all()]
```

Comment: you can search about MultiValue field and use it with comment_set attribute in restaurat model.

Comment: Thanks. I actually read the manual, but didn't know how to add the comments in my RestaurantIndex. Do you mean using:
comment = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comment_set') in my RestaurantIndex? If so, how can I specify which fields of the Comment model must be indexed?

Comment: No, i can't find the correct link but i mean something like:

    class RestaurantIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
        comments = indexes.indexes.MultiValueField()
        def prepare_comments(self, obj):
            return [a for a in obj.comment_set.all()]

Comment: Maybe this worked in the past, but in the current state of things, the above would return a `TypeError` saying that `Comment object ... is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I understand that, and you're right, the question was asked in 2010, and was answered for the code in that time.